What is the project Id in Cloud Tasks
In Cloud Tasks in callBack functions you get a projectId as in const project = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG).projectId;.
What is the projectId and how do I get it?

Google Cloud projects are the "root" collections in your Google Cloud organization. You can get the id of a project from the project dropdown selector. This is located in the left-side header of https://console.cloud.google.com/ next to the Google Cloud logo. For each project, you will see both the project name and it's id.

The wording are the "root" collections is not correct. A Google Cloud project is one type of resource in a hierarchy of resources. In this example, each item is a resource showing the location of an attached persistent disk within an organization: ORG, Folder, Project, Compute Engine, Persistent Disk. Notice that the project is not the root of anything.
